# “context deadline exceeded” error when running a system command inside Fly machine

Tags: c++, fly

I have a cpp application that I have compiled on fly machine

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Please enter some text: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << "You entered: " << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to run the compiled executable like this `./program < input.txt` .

contents of input.txt looks like this `Hello, this is input from a file.`

When I send that command over their REST API

```
{
    "cmd": "./program < input.txt"
}
```

, I get an error

```
{
    "error": "deadline_exceeded: Post \"http://unix/v1/exec\": context deadline exceeded"
}
```

I think it is because of the input redirection command or the `cin` ?? Any idea on what to do now?

Comment: What is a fly machine?

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri sorry. fly machine is a VM in the cloud. https://fly.io/docs/machines/working-with-machines/

Comment: Random guess: `cmd` is not being interpreted by a shell. Try wrapping your command in a bash invocation like so: `{"cmd": "bash -c \"./program < input.txt\""}`

Comment: thanks @Botje . `sh -c "./program < input.txt"` passing it like this fixed it. Can you please make your comment the answer so that I can mark it as a soln?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this `cmd` argument is not interpreted by a shell. This means that your program receives the literal arguments `<` and `input.txt` but nothing is ever sent to STDIN.

If you wrap your command in a `bash -c` invocation the shell will do that for you:

```
bash -c './program < input.txt'
```